# It wont let me turn my button to be interactable from other script

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Recently I have been getting into Unity and have started making my first game. I am really happy with it but recently I have been getting really annoyed.

I have made a level system in my game (once you complete the first level (all level are separate scenes)you move on to the next level). I have found out how to use `application.loadlevel`, etc. **But I also want the level menu** (where you can select your past levels or current one by clicking a button) to turn intractability on **once you have completed the previous level by picking up a cube**. Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to do it as all my scripts have failed.

Please help me and thanks in advance and I am a beginner so don't explain things too advanced. Just tell me what to do and what I need to write in my scripts. If I have to use prefabs please tell me how as that confuses me as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to save somewhere that you have completed a level. This information must be saved in a persistent manner, otherwise, your player will have to restart your whole game each time he launches your game. There are many ways to do so, but [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) could be a starting point.

Once any level is completed (before loading the next scene), call the following function :

```
public void OnLevelCompleted()
{
    // Retrieve name of current scene / level
    string sceneName = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt( sceneName, 1 ) ; // Indicates the level is completed
}
```

Then, in your home scene, attach a script to your buttons with the following piece of code :

```
public string SceneName ; // Indicate which level this button must load once you click on it. Be carefull, the name must be the same as in your Build Settings

 protected void Awake()
 {
     UnityEngine.UI.Button button = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();

     if( button != null )
     {
          // Make the button load the given scene
          button.onClick.AddListener( () => UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene( SceneName ) ) ;

          // Make the button interactable only if the given scene / level has been completed
          button.interactable = PlayerPrefs.GetInt( SceneName ) > 0 ;
     }
     else
         Debug.LogWarning("No button component attached", this ) ;
 }
```